# Use Case / UML scenario for App and an external system

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I am currently working on the use cases for a car sharing app.

The simple diagram for the process of registration looks like this:

[image: UML diagram for registration]

At the moment I am stuck with the following scenarios.
When a new customer is registered, a process is carried out at the head office (central)in which the following points are checked

Scenario 1 - Head office side:

> 

*1. The identity of new customers is carried out **externally** with
the post. Two possibilities: presenting the identity card at a post office branchor carrying out by video.
2. The verification of the customer's bank details is carried out **externally** with the bank.
3.The system will verify that the contact details (email address) are correct
4.the consent to the GTC has been obtained*

My sketch for the confirmation process looks like this:

[image: confirmation process]

How do I show that the system verifies that the contact details (email address) is correct ? How do I show that consent to the GTC has been given ?

Scenario 2 - Customer's side: A customer can view and edit the information of his registration.

*1.Edit profile data
2.Edit contact information
3.Edit bank details.
If information is changed during editing, verification must be carried out again by the head office.*

What would the two use case diagrams look like ?

Comment: Identity confirmtion is no use case but some sort of constraint. You do not describe a scenario with use cases but with activity diagrams (related to UC scenarios).

Answer (score 1):

Just to stress this fact: you do NOT describe a scenario with use cases. A use case is "just" to show the added value a system under consideration delivers to one of its actors. What you are asking is functional decomposition and that's just plain wrong. You would describe a scenario with an activity diagram (or as plain text like in the Cockburn way).

Answer (score 0):

### One or two apps?

*(Posted before diagrams were added to the question)*

Nothing in the narrative says that you need two systems. It's too early to decide about system architecture. You could have the following variants, each with pros and cons:

- one and the same system (e.g. post office and customer access it via the web);
- one and the same system that is accessible using different components on different devices (e.g. a rich client in the post office,  a web interface for the customer on her mac/PC and a mobile app for a customer when using a smartphone);
- several independent systems (e.g. a back office in the post-office, and an independent app that would connect not only to the back office,  but also to other back-end services e.g. from other companies).

But how do you want to decide before first knowing what is needed and how the needs are related?

First, you have to understand the **big picture** of what's needed. Focus on the users not on the inner details of your solutions, as explained in the UML specifications:

> UseCases are a means to capture the requirements of systems, i.e., what systems are supposed to do. (...)
> a UseCase (...) specifies a set of behaviors (...), which yields an observable result that is of value for Actors or other stakeholders (...)
> (...) **without reference to its internal structure**

Look into your narrative to find actors (people, organisation, responsibilities), their goals (what do they need to do?) and how they could relate to each other.  Just try a first sketch.

### Your current model

*(Posted after the diagrams were added)*

I still see no reason to go for 2 distinct systems.  You are working on a solution for car sharing.  It may have different sub-systems/components, but the actors do not care.  And neither does your customer.   But:

- If you'd go for two independent systems,  you'd draw two disginct diagrams, and in each diagram you'd have an actor representing the other system that interacts with the system under consideration. As said, this makes sense only if it's an independent system.
- In your case, I could imagine this for the bank account verification and the video identity verification:  unless you intend to develop your own super-secured AI component capable of doing this,  you'd probably outsource this to a specialized company, that may offer this service via an automated API.

The identify verification is at a different level of details than the other use-cases.  You may want to show it in a separate diagram, in order not to pollute the main diagram.

And lastly,  your second diagram has some issues:

- the arrows of extend and include should not following the same direction: the target of an include is the included use case whereas the target of the extend arrow should be the use case that is extended (and not the use case that is extending the normal use case as you have shown).
- `ID correct` and `Bank correct` are states.  Use cases do not show states.  The end-state can be specified in the description of the use-case but not in the use-case diagram.
- `Post office`, `Bank account`, `Video` seem to be use-cases, but they are not well described.

A possible diagram could therefore be:

[image: Details of the registration confirmation in a use-case diagram]

Note: I'd personally prefer specialization  of `Ensure identity`.  This corresponds more to the reality that there are two very distinct behaviors.  But extension is ok.

Comment: I edit my post. You'll find a UML for the process of register and a raw sketch about identification process.

Comment: @me4gqp I see.; I've edited my answer accordingly.  Hope this helps.

Comment: i update my post again. The Head Office (Central) is an Actor.

Comment: @me4gqp You can add the central office as actor for the confirm registration of there is any supervisory fonction involved, or if it’s a proxy for the different users that could be involved. Contact adresse verification is usually done with an email sent to the user who has to click on a link or provide an id code to the system. In both case it’s an interaction with a use-case. But this can be provided as info for the confirmation UC. No need to get lost in details on such a diagram: this is functional decomposition or user interface design and UCD is not meant for that.

Comment: It would help me if you could demonstrate on the UML diagram I provided how to include the confirmation of the email address and the confirmation of the GTC.

Comment: Pls. see my comment above,

Comment: @ qwerty_so I read your comment. Yes, it is a Use Case Diagram. But I'll specify my post again.

Comment: @me4gqp while we can argue about identity verification being or not a use-case (in some environments, identity management is some people's main goal, identify verification can be complex, and in your case it's an important part of the requirements and value), the email verification seems to be a trivial detail that does not change fundamentally use-cases.  As previously said:  use-case diagrams are not a substitute for describing the behavior expected behind its title; use-cases are not for visual programming; and use-cases are not the right tool for designing a user-interface either.

Comment: so on the email verification, I'd completely agree with @qwerty_so and would not change anything in the diagram.  If you think it's really necessary,  you could still replicate the approach proposed for other topics here (but I'd really not advise to do it ).